# Как перезагрузить картинку, загруженную через NSData(contentsOfURL:)

Tags: ios, swift

Я загружаю картинки с сервера через вот такой метод:

```swift
    func imgfromlink(link url: String) -> UIImage? {
        if let iurl = NSURL(string: url) {
            if let idata = NSData(contentsOfURL: iurl) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: idata){
                    return image
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Суть такова: в метод я передаю ссылку на картинку, а на выходе получаю UIImage.
Но у меня есть маленькая проблема. Если картинка на сервере обновилась (урл картинки остаётся тот же), и я пробую загрузить эту картинку заново через этот метод, то она не обновляется.

Я подумал, наверное она кешируется и попробовал поковырять `NSData` и нашёл там такой ключ `options: .DataReadingUncached`

Я переделал свой метод:

```swift
    func imgfromlinkUncached(link url: String) -> UIImage? {
            if let iurl = NSURL(string: url) {
                do {
                    let idata = try NSData(contentsOfURL: iurl, options: .DataReadingUncached)
                    if let image = UIImage(data: idata){
                        return image
                    }
                }
                catch _ {
                    return nil
                }
            }
        return nil
    }
```

Но ничего не изменилось. Картинки не обновляются. А для меня это критично, так как пользователь должен иметь возможность сменить аватарку и везде должна отображаться обновлённая версия аватарки, но url аватарки остаётся неизменным, меняется только картинка на сервере.

Версия xcode 8.0

Comment: Можете пожалуйста предоставить больше кода? Возможно ошибка не в этой функции, а например в том, что вы не обновляете переменную, хранящую результат выполнения данной функции.

Comment: Офтоп, но я всё же должен это сказать - вообще не стоит так делать, лучше использовать какой-нибудь готовый LazyImage, ибо в конце концов твой подход будет иметь определённые слабые места

Comment: Погуглил - похоже твой подход с `NSDataReadingUncached` должен работать. Есть ещё один подход - дописывать к урлу "?random="+случайное число

Comment: @markov Может человек разобраться хочет с тем как это всё устроено.

Comment: @RomanPodymov у меня есть ссылка на картинку, кнопка, в которую я загружаю изображение, получаемое по той ссылке через функцию указанную выше в посте. Когда пользователь выбрал аватарку с устройства она сразу загружается в кнопку вместо прошлой картинки, скачанной с интернета. И после этого пользователь нажимает другую кнопку, которая отправляет картинку на сервер, где эта картинка заменяет предыдущую и становится доступна по той старой ссылке. После этого я заново вызываю функцию описанную в посте, где получаю картинку из ссылки и загружаю её в кнопку.

Comment: @markov да, метод с рандомными цифрами и вопросом сработал, спасибо. Получается теперь нет необходимости использовать NSDataReadingUncached?